# High Pass Filter for Image using C++ and Python

Tags: python, highpass-filter

I was assigned to optimize the HPF using C++. Fyi, the original image is 512x512.

By getting the .dat file that is produced by using Python script, I applied a 5x5 HPF on it with 2 zero-pad with stride = 1 so the result image is still in 512x512. By using the custom algorithm, the HPF result is shown in the Manual HPF result. Since it is different with the result as shown in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6094957/high-pass-filter-for-image-processing-in-python-by-using-scipy-numpy , may I know is this Manual HPF result acceptable?

The *.dat file is a list of number as shown below which is generated by using C++. The result of the convolution between the Image matrix and 5x5 high pass filter kernel is being threshold where it is equal to 0 if the result is smaller than 0 and equal to 255 if the result is larger than 255

```
64
127
255
.
.
.
.
.
0
41
```

Then, the Python script (as shown below) is used to convert the list of number into the 2D array. Then this 2D array is converted into 512*512 greyscale image.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

file = "ans.dat"
pixel = []
convertedPixel = []
z = 0
arr = np.zeros((512,512))

with open(file) as data_file:
    for line in data_file:
        line_list = line.replace(' ',',')
        line_list = line_list.replace(',\n','')
        pixel.append(int(line_list))
        pixel.append(int(line_list))
        pixel.append(int(line_list))

array = np.array(pixel)

for i in array:
    if i > 255:
        i = 255
    if i < 0:
        i = 0
array = np.uint8(array)
array = array.reshape(512,512,3)
print(array)
'''
f = open('check.dat', 'w')
for i in range (0, len(array)):
    f.write(str(array[i])+"\n")
f.close()
'''
#new_image = Image.fromarray(array)
#new_image = new_image.convert("RGB")
#new_image.save('new.png')
```

[Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gdi2Z.gif)[Manual HPF Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTgoq.png)

Comment: What's acceptable or not depends on the specific requirements of your application. Why are doing high-pass filtering in the first place, how good does it need to be and how exactly do you define "good" for your specific task

Comment: Actually I was assigned to improve the convolution algorithm by using pthread. But before that I would like to confirm that the convolution between the high pass filter kernel and the image matrix is correct as it is different from this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/M24re.png . So I would like to ask for confirmation is my method works actually or not.

Comment: Fyi, I am applying 5x5 hpf filter (http://www.bluevoid.com/opengl/sig00/advanced00/notes/node265.html) on my image matrix and the result is shown in the question section

Comment: For a filter this small, multithreading will pose more overhead than it increases your performance. Have you actually benchmarked where time is spent?

Comment: (multithreading won't help at all if you're IO bound. And you're not doing any signal processing here – just reading a file)